# Grouped dropdown list box caption overflows

Tags: html, css

My grouped dropdown list box looks like this,

[image]

JSfiddle code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F3KyK/668/).

Issue No.1) When the caption is lenghty as `Grouped dropdown box`, it pushes the inverted triangle to the next line. When i reduce the caption length, the icon falls into line as,

[image]

Issue No.2) Setting `overflow:hidden` on `ul` caption doesn't hide the overflowing content. And again, `text-overflow:ellipsis` on the list items is not showing any triple dots.

Comment: can you please make your points more clearer.What do you want your output to be

Comment: .list-item-name {
   white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 9em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
 
 }

please try this..

Answer (score 4):

Textoverflow is working only with block or inline-block elements. Add `display: inline-block;` to your span tag to make it work:

```
.btn-text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

See [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzoLwj).

**UPDATE**

Don't apply the overflow on `.drp-down-cnt` div, but on the list-item itself:

```
.list-item-name{
   width: 150px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

In similar way, this can by applied to `.group-header`

Updated [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaMmrM)

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your `fiddle`. Check here.
Issue 2 is resolved but Issue 1 is temporary solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use OPTION and OPTGROUP tag instead of this div,ul,and li. They are much more convenient and easy. Here it is :-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>

                <select>
                <option value="opt123">Grouped drop down box caption</option>
                <optgroup label="I am group one">
                    <option value="opt11">I am child one's child longgggggggggggggg</option>
                    <option value="opt12">I am one's child two</option>
                    <option value="opt13">I am one's child three</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="I am group two">
                    <option value="opt21">I am 2's child one</option>
                    <option value="opt22">I am 2's child two</option>
                    <option value="opt23">I am 2's child three</option>
                </optgroup>
                </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.list-item-name { 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 9em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

please try this